# How to set the value of a vizframe id to another variable ( using this.getView().byId) using sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I am using the using the sap webide. In my application I have some vizcharts binded to Odata. Now I am trying to download the vizcharts as PDF. But I am unable to get the value of vizcharts.
Below is my code from JS controller.

```
downloadClickHandler: function(oEvent) {var str = "width=500px,height=600px";
        var wind = window.open("", "PrintWindow", str);
        var chart = this.getView().byId("idVizFrameCountofTransactionUsed");
        var Details = chart["sId"];wind.document.write(Details);
        wind.print();
        wind.close();
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by:

```
_onDownload : function() {
  var oVizFrame = this.byId("chartContainerVizFrame");
  var oModel = oVizFrame.getModel();
  var oData = oModel.oData;
}
```

In oData object now you have data from the chart. Please have a look in this [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/tWrC9ABW1YNVHL1v0HbR?p=preview), and press download icon.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want to capture the ui representation of graph in PDF. Odata  is giving me only data from chart .